# How to pass a class to make invisible in the input field of YII?

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('CAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'search',
    'id'=>'input-box',
    'attribute'=>'search',
    'url'=> $this->createAbsoluteUrl('products/suggestions'),
    'value'=>($_GET['search'] == '')?'Search for Mobiles, Cameras & Laptops':$_GET['search'],
    'minChars'=>2,
    'scroll'=>false,
    'resultsClass'=>'searchAutoComplete ac_results',
    'htmlOptions'=> array(
    'class'=>'searchClickClear',
    ),
    'methodChain'=>'.result(function(){$("form#search-form").submit();})'
));
?>
```

This is my widget for taking input, and I am passing the class `searchAutoComplete`. What the class should be? What I want is, when I click on the field the value will be empty.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear, I could not understand what you need

Comment: As above. Do you mean you want to remove the string 'Search for Mobiles, Cameras & Laptops' from the input when a user clicks on the input?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on input field, event `onclick` is going on.
So, you can handle it and change input value to empty. Howto?

Change your 'htmlOptions' like this:

> 'htmlOptions'=> array(
>       'onclick'=>'$("#input-box").val("")';
>     ),

*#input-box* - css-selector of your input.

*val()* - jQuery method for setting some value to elements. See [more info](http://api.jquery.com/val/) about this method

*resultsClass* - the CSS class for the dropdown list. Defaults to "ac_results".  [More info](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAutoComplete#resultsClass-detail)

For the task solution you don't need change `resultsClass` from the default value. Remove this string.